libssl.so.1.1 missing on Ubuntu 24.04
I recently installed ubuntu 24.04 and got the message that libssl.so.1.1 is missing.
How to install libssl.so.1.1 on ubuntu 24.04?

You randomly got the message out of nowhere?

This issue is related to Ubuntu 24.04 and its answer also points to a newer version of libssl,

The issue is common to all versions of Ubuntu starting from 22.04, and is hardly specific to 24.04. If you have found a newer version's URL, consider editing one of the many answers in the duplicate that provide links to this package and updating it.

After some research I found how to download and install it.
curl -O http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.22_amd64.deb


So now you have an outdated and possibly vulnerable version of libssl on your system - just so you are aware of this fact.

Might be outdated, but tor is running now. and btw. asterirsk also needs this outdated lib. And I wonder who else needs this lib too.
